# Need to understand SOAP 1.2 web-service data calling/sending in PHP

Tags: php, html, web-services

I understand what a SOAP web-service is, but I need to know how to call for data and how to store data in it (specially in PHP), and what the difference between both methods are.

I have the URL and the XML structure examples (in a physical, paper copy), but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you start: use php SoapClient

```
      $client = new SoapClient('url?WSDL', array(
        'trace' => true,
      ));
      var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Comment: I am aware of this bit, what I don't understand right now is how to begin performing calls/how to write data to it.

Comment: start using SoapUI to have a better understanding of the application